# Django and celery: What is the need for setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE for the 'celery' program since its already set in manage.py

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

While i was understanding how to use celery i found the following

```
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.settings')
app = Celery('projectname')
```

In the above code we are setting the env variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

It's the same thing we do in the manage.py

```
def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.settings')
```

Since `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` its being set in the manage.py why to set it again in celery

I checked the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is already set. I commented out and printed the env variable:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
#os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.settings')

print("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE [celery.py] : ",os.environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"))

app = Celery('projectname')
```

then

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

output:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE [celery.py] :  projectname.settings
```

So i feel its not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so that celery can auto discover tasks in your app modules. Celery isn't started with `manage.py` it's started similar to below

```
$ celery -A proj worker -l info
```

When this command is run in the shell Celery executes the code in `proj/celery.py` which exports Django settings and looks for `tasks.py` in your project apps.

Comment: I didnt understant. For me it appears both the codes are executed inside manage.py. Definitely Celery is started seperately, but where are we passing this `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` info to celery

Comment: I was checking it with `python manage.py runserver`, instead when i checked with `celery -A app -l info` then i found that DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is not set. Because celery wants the tasks to be registered, which are mentioned using `CELERY_IMPORTS = (
    'app.tasks',
)`

Answer (score 1):

We set a default value for the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable to be the python path to our settings file. This environment variable is used by Django to define which settings file it should load and it will allow us importing the settings with from django.conf import settings which we want to use in the respective file.

The purpose of defining it again in celery.py inside Django app is because celery run's as a separate service whereas our django server runs separately.

Hope this helps and clarify your doubts!!!